# Github saving changes in chinese

Tags: php, git, github

Hi recentyl I added a file to my github repo but all the changes seem to be saved in chinese but my code is all in php.

Here is a screenshot of my current status.

http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=22644

Comment: check in that in website, probably it's encoding problem

Comment: Check encoding. Treating an `utf8` file as `utf16` often produces Chinese letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i was working with this type of characters á,é,í the time before i did the commit showed me those chinese characters but after the initial commit all the code was showed and those characters were marked with the rhombus and the question mark inside.

shake shake